# React router and UseContext

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I have a Login and Dashboard component, as well as a context that stores the state of is Loading and setIsLoading, in the login component after I clicked the isLogin button, it is updated, but it is not updated in the Dashboard component
If you do this without ReactRouter, then everything is OK, the isLoading will not change with it

App

```
import "./App.scss";
import React from "react";
import Card from "./Component/Card/Card";
import List from "./Component/list/list";
import axios from "axios";
import Header from "./Component/Header/Header";
import Login from "./pages/Login";
import Dashboard from "./pages/Dashboard";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

export const AppContext = React.createContext();
function App() {
  const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = React.useState(false);
  const [products, setProducts] = React.useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header></Header>
      <AppContext.Provider value={{ isLogin, setIsLogin }}>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/dash" element={<Dashboard />} />
        </Routes>
      </AppContext.Provider>  
     </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Login

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import { LoginContext } from "../LogincContext";
import { AppContext } from "../App";
const Login = () => {
  const { isLogin, setIsLogin } = useContext(AppContext);

  const handleLogin = () => {
    setIsLogin(true);
    console.log("Login", isLogin);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
      <button onClick={handleLogin}>Log in</button>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Login;
```

Dashboard

```
import React from "react";
import { AppContext } from "../App";
const Dashboard = () => {
  const { isLogin } = React.useContext(AppContext);

  console.log(isLogin);

  return (
    <div>
      {isLogin ? (
        <div>Welcome to the store!</div>
      ) : (
        <div>Please log in to access the store.</div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

Everything works without router

Comment: How do you navigate between routes?

Comment: React router version : "^6.11.1",

Comment: @Konrad Changing the link in the address bar

Comment: I'm pretty sure that changing the url in the address bar will unload all js variables. Try using the `Link` element

Comment: YEAH, thank you
Sorry for my bad english
Good luck!)